# Connect to SQL Server through PDO : DATABASE on another server

Tags: pdo, sql-server-2012, port, driver

On local PC this works.

```
$HmsDBuser     = 'test';
$HmsDBpassword = 'password';
$HmsDBserver   = 'Developer,1433';
$HmsDBdatabase = 'DBNAME';     
    $this->db = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$HmsDBserver;Database=$HmsDBdatabase","$HmsDBuser","$HmsDBpassword", array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

My Slim Framework is on Server A: 121.55.0.25
My database is on another Server B: 121.55.0.21

```
$HmsDBuser     = 'test';
$HmsDBpassword = 'password';
$HmsDBserver   = '121.55.0.21\MYSERVER\MSSQLSERVER,1433';
$HmsDBdatabase = 'DBNAME';   

$this->db = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$HmsDBserver;Database=$HmsDBdatabase","$HmsDBuser","$HmsDBpassword", array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

and after I connect to the database, I call function with path "product" in Slim framework. 
ERROR got on Console : 
angular.js:8619 GET http://121.55.0.25/product-manager_servertest/api/v1/products 404 (Not Found)

Comment: *and after I connect to the database, I call some function in slim framework.

I cannot connect to database.*  this is confusing

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$HmsDBserver = '121.55.0.21\\MYSERVER\\MSSQLSERVER,1433';
```

Notes:

- Escaped backslashes.
- No space before port.

If it doesn't work, then use just the [server name](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hostname-server-name-droplet-name-and-domain-name), like this:

```
$HmsDBserver = '<server-name>,1433';
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall? It seems that the port 1433 is blocked.

Comment: I have another project on the same server which uses odbc database connection and uses port 1433  , so firewall blocking the port 1433 cannot be the issue.

Comment: Thank you aendeerei for trying to help me :-)  although we not yet to a solution

Comment: You are welcome. Then it's something about the given rights of the db service. But I give up :-) Good luck, @Pax!